# Command Line App Creation for HP Touchpad

Tags: webos, enyo, touchpad

I have recently started venturing into some HP webOS development and I am wondering if anyone knows if there is a code-generation command similar to the webOS Mojo palm-generate tool.

Comment: palm-generate

Generates applications and scenes.

Note: Currently, only generating Mojo apps is supported. Found the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we have caught up on the tooling yet, we were focusing on launching the framework & OS in time for the TouchPad.